# jQuery plugin to replace multi select form element (listbox)

Tags: jquery, html

So the jQuery plugin site is down and my google foo has let me down. I have a select form element that has multi select enable. Basically, it is a list box. The problem with using the standard form element is that some times the items in the list box can get longer than the width of the list box. I have found that horizontal scroll bars do not work very will with the stand form element. So I am looking for a jquery plugin that is basically a list box that has horizontal scroll bars.

Looks and styles wise, the html list box is fine. It just needs to have a working horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: can't you just fix the box in CSS? jQuery is helpful para is not an universal panacea.

Comment: That is what I thought...  If I force the scroll bar or do other tricks like put the select element in a div, it makes it worse. So I am either doing something wrong or it is just broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take  a look at this `selectbox` jQuery plugin. I hope this might help you.

http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/

Comment: Looks like it may work. Need to do a few styling changes to get the scroll bar to work! Thank you.

Comment: @Tony - Yes, you will have to add some styles for scroll bar and font color etc to match your requirement. Mark this as an answer if this helped you thanks.